# multiprocessing with serial port

Tags: python, python-2.7

I've a target board which sends me CPU load for every 1sec which communicates through serial port. I want to write a python code which reads data from serial port for every 1sec second and writes to a file and also it should check for user input i.e. if user enters command it should pass that command to target board.

Answer (score 3):

You can create two threads, one listening for user input, the other polling the serial port every second. Check out [threading](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html) for information on multithreading in python and [pyserial](http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/shortintro.html) for information on reading from serial ports. The threading package provides your desired repetition functionality: https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#timer-objects

**[EDIT]**

Sample code, obviously replace `/dev/ttyS1` with the desired port and do something useful with the user input:

```
import serial
import threading
def read_from_serial():
  # port = "/dev/ttyS1"
  # ser = serial.Serial(port, 19200, timeout = 1)
  # print ser.readline()
  # ser.close()
  print "read"
  threading.Timer(1, read_from_serial).start()


if __name__ == "__main__":
  serial_thread = threading.Thread(target = read_from_serial())
  serial_thread.start()
  while True:
    print raw_input("User input: ")
```

Comment: Though you should be aware that because of Python's Global Interpreter Lock, you can't execute 2 Threads at the same time, meaning the Threading module will switch between your thread constantly, and it is not really parallelized execution. If you need real multiprocessing, there is the multiprocessing module to help you.

Comment: Can you tell how it can be done using multiprocessing?